# Android simple stuff about scrolling

Tags: android, scroll

As I don't know how to ask it to google, I'll try here.

I basically have a listView displayed from an intent. This listView is feeded by a custom BaseAdapter.

This listView is actually a calendar. I want on the opening of the activity having this calendar listView that it has been already scrolled to te current day.

Basically I'm asking how can I pre-scroll a listview to an index of the listView ? Is this possible ? With a function of custom BaseAdapter ?

Thanks.

Comment: Calendar and its implemented by ListView, so one suggestion is here it should be better displayed using GridView.

Comment: are you try to use `public void setSelection (int position)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use,

```
list.setSelection(index);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of following methods -
This method to save save list scroll position.

```
private void saveListScrollPosition() {
    // save index and top position
    index = _listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View view = _listview.getChildAt(0);
    top = (view == null) ? 0 : view.getTop();
}
```

And this one to get it back and scroll it down automatically -

```
private void restoreListScrollPosition() {
    // restore
    _listview.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
}
```

I think in your case, index will be the current date. Right?